# git clone してローカルで書き換えたライブラリを使用したい

Tags: python3

#### 前提

ライブラリをクローンして、ローカルで書き換えたものを使用したいと思っています。
以下のライブラリを使用
https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode

#### 実現したいこと

`git clone` し、`pip install -e [cloneしたディレクトリ] /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/site-packages` でローカルでライブラリを書き換えたものをインストールしようとしていた。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ERROR: .python-qrcode/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/site-packages is not
 a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning
 with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, 
git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, 
svn+svn, svn+file).
```

#### 試したこと

`pip show [cloneしたライブラリ名]` でローカルのパスを調べた。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

古いバージョンのpythonで同様の操作を行なって、"前提"に書いていることは実現できていたが、バージョンを変更したことでできなくなった。

Comment: 他の人が再現できるよう、対象のライブラリやどのように書き換えたのかといった情報も記載があると回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[How can I install a modified version of a Python library without negating/overwriting the original package?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-a-modified-version-of-a-Python-library-without-negating-overwriting-the-original-package), [GitHub のプライベートリポジトリから Python の独自パッケージをインストールしてみた](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/github-private-repository-for-python-package/), [Install and Import Modified Package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56914464/9014308)